# minikube cluster will not pull in images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, kubectl, minikube

I am having issues pulling in my images of my minihkube kubemaniest file for what ever reason.

Here is how it looks:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: afsim-controller
      name: afsim-controller
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: "5000"
          port: 5000
          targetPort: 5000
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: afsim-controller
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: 'mdo-geo'
      name: 'mdo-geo'
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: "5006"
          port: 5006
          targetPort: 5006
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: 'mdo-geo'
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: mdo-net
      name: mdo-net
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: "5009"
          port: 5009
          targetPort: 5009
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: mdo-net
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: 'afsim-controller'
      name: 'afsim-controller'
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: 'afsim-controller'
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
            kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: 'afsim-controller'
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: MSG_SERVICE
                - name: MSG_SERVICE_HOST
                - name: MSG_SERVICE_PORT
                - name: NETWORK_BEHAVIOR
                  value: /home/python3/network_behavior.yaml
                - name: SERVICE_PORT
                  value: "5000"
                - name: USE_NET
                  value: "1"
              image: docker-ng-repo.ms.northgrum.com/aic/mdo_afsim_controller
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              name: 'afsim-controller'
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5000
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /home/python3/network_behavior.yaml
                  name: afsim-controller-hostpath0
                - mountPath: /scenarios
                  name: afsim-controller-hostpath1
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - hostPath:
                path: /home/jsikala/mdo_startup/network_behavior.yaml
              name: afsim-controller-hostpath0
            - hostPath:
                path: /home/jsikala/mdo_afsim/scenarios/MDO
              name: afsim-controller-hostpath1
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: mdo-geo
      name: mdo-geo
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: mdo-geo
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
            kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: mdo-geo
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: MSG_SERVICE
                  value: kafka
                - name: MSG_SERVICE_HOST
                  value: localhost
                - name: MSG_SERVICE_PORT
                  value: "5006"
                - name: NETWORK_BEHAVIOR
                  value: /home/python3/network_behavior.yaml
                - name: PLATFORM
                  value: uuv_1
                - name: SERVICE_PORT
                  value: "5006"
                - name: USE_NET
                  value: "1"
              image: docker-ng-repo.ms.northgrum.com/aic/mdo_geo
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              name: mdo-geo
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5006
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /home/python3/network_behavior.yaml
                  name: mdo-geo-hostpath0
                - mountPath: /Data2/MDO/geo_data
                  name: mdo-geo-hostpath1
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - hostPath:
                path: /home/jsikala/mdo_startup/network_behavior.yaml
              name: mdo-geo-hostpath0
            - hostPath:
                path: /home/jsikala/mdo_startup/geo_data
              name: mdo-geo-hostpath1
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: 'mdo-net'
      name: 'mdo-net'
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: 'mdo-net'
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath -o kubemanifest.yaml
            kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: 'mdo-net'
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: MSG_SERVICE
                  value: kafka
                - name: MSG_SERVICE_HOST
                  value: localhost
                - name: MSG_SERVICE_PORT
                  value: "5009"
                - name: NETWORK_CONFIG
                  value: /home/python3/network_config.yaml
                - name: SERVICE_PORT
                  value: "5009"
              image: docker-ng-repo.ms.northgrum.com/aic/mdo_net
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              name: mdo-net
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5009
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /home/python3/network_config.yaml
                  name: mdo-net-hostpath0
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - hostPath:
                path: /home/jsikala/mdo_startup/network_config.yaml
              name: mdo-net-hostpath0
    status: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

When I attempt to get the pods I see this:

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
afsim-controller-777cf55c4-vf4b9   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          20h
mdo-geo-588b9d46-2hrnk             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          20h
mdo-net-6f44d9d6c5-bpw4k           0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          20h
```

I have pull the images locally, yet still can not get the images to be pull by minikube. I've also  added an `imagePullPolicy` and still am getting the `ImagePullBackOff` error. Any idea what maybe causing this issue?

Comment: The `image:` you have looks like it points at a private Docker image registry; do you need authentication of some sort to use it?  You might try to clean up some of what Kompose has generated; things like the `hostPath:` volumes won't really work in Kubernetes.

Comment: You are trying to reach private registry docker-ng-repo.ms.northgrum.com. If you downloaded the images local . What do you mean by that ? Did you mean that you downloaded images in the docket repo: docker-ng-repo.ms.northgrum.com?

Answer (score 0):

If the images are in a private registry, you should use an *imagePullSecret*

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/